# How do I yank into the system register from v-imode?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to yank text from a zsh command while in vi-mode with `y` and paste it into my web-browser/text-editor, etc.

Currently it seems that yanking text while in vi-mode only allows pasting back into zsh- has anyone had success yanking into the system clipboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a widget that executes the internal `vi-yank` widget and copies the zle clipboard (current position in kill ring) to the X11 clipboard using `xclip(1)`:

```
function vi-yank-xclip {
    zle vi-yank
   echo "$CUTBUFFER" | xclip -i
}
```

.Replace `xclip -i` with `pbcoby` if running Mac OSX.

Make that widget known to zle and bind it to `y`:

```
zle -N vi-yank-xclip
bindkey -M vicmd 'y' vi-yank-xclip
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  For other osx users, `pbcopy` can be used instead of `zclip`