# Yank in visual (Vim) mode in zsh does not copy to clipboard in ordert to paste with Ctrl + d in other applications

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, copy-paste, key-bindings

I recently moved from `bash` to `zsh` and use vim keybindings in `zsh`.

When I highlight a string in visual and yank it with <kbd>y</kbd>, I can then paste it inside of zsh without problem. However when I try to paste that same string outside of `zsh` (with the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>) it does not work. Instead the last copied item with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is copied there.

Is there an additional command to write in the `.zshrc`?

Comment: Shells have their own internal buffers. You could use something like pbcopy/xclip depending on your system

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @D.BenKnoble. Do you have any idea about which command I should write in the `.zshrc`?

Answer (score 6):

By default zsh yanks to its own internal registers. Luckily, like in Vim, it's fairly simple yank to the system clipboard.

```
# vi mode
bindkey -v

# Yank to the system clipboard
function vi-yank-xclip {
    zle vi-yank
   echo "$CUTBUFFER" | pbcopy -i
}

zle -N vi-yank-xclip
bindkey -M vicmd 'y' vi-yank-xclip
```

Replace `pbcopy` with the method of your system, for example `xclip` if you're on Linux.

Further reading and a couple alternatives at:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25765/pasting-from-clipboard-to-vi-enabled-zsh-or-bash-shell
- [How do I yank into the system register from v-imode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398532/how-do-i-yank-into-the-system-register-from-v-imode)

(Which this question is a duplicate of.)

Answer (score 0):

You first have to be sure that your vim installation has clipboard support. Open vim and type:

```
:version
```

You'll see the features included in your installation have a `+` next to them, those that aren't have a `-`, for example:

```
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
.
.
.

+clientserver      -footer            +mouse_netterm     +smartindent       +wildmenu
+clipboard         +fork()            +mouse_sgr         +startuptime       +windows
.
.
.
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^ see here that clipboard is included. If you don't have clipboard support, see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313409/11743318) on how to get it in MacOS.

Once you have `+clipboard` you can yank into the system clipboard by first typing `"+` to tell vim to use the *'+ register'* (see [How do I use vim registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers)), followed by the normal `y` to yank the text.

Comment: Thanks but this question is about `zsh` with vim-style keybindings, not Vim.

Comment: Actually this response lead me to the actual issue. I was trying to figure out why I can't copy to global keyboard in vim when using zsh, when actually the problem was my Ubuntu 22.04 did not include a vim with clipboard support.